# Filtered WPF textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a textbox which filters user input to match specified type, so I can discard some of my validation logic.

For example, if I specify `ushort` I want my textbox to only accept text changes which result in a valid `ushort` value and nothing else.

This is what I've ended up with:

```
public abstract class CustomTextBox<T> : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(T), typeof(CustomTextBox<T>), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(T), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnValueChanged));
    public T Value
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_regex != null && !_regex.IsMatch(e.Text))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            return;
        }

        T val;
        if (!TryParse(out val))
        {
            var index = CaretIndex;
            Text = _validText;
            CaretIndex = index > 0 ? index - 1 : 0;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Value = val;
            _validText = Text;

        }
    }

    protected CustomTextBox(string regexPattern = null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(regexPattern))
        {
            _regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
        }
        _validText = ToString(Value);

        Loaded += OnTextboxLoaded;
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateText();

        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected virtual string ToString(T value)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    protected abstract bool TryParse(out T val);

    private readonly Regex _regex;
    private string _validText;

    private void ValidateText()
    {
        T val;
        if (!TryParse(out val))
        {
            Text = ToString(Value);
        }
    }

    private void OnTextboxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateText();
    }

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (CustomTextBox<T>)d;
        if (!e.OldValue.Equals(e.NewValue))
        {
            var str = tb.ToString((T)e.NewValue);
            if (!str.Equals(tb.Text))
            {
                tb.Text = str;
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

`ushort` implementation:

```
public sealed class UshortTextBox : CustomTextBox<ushort>
{
    public UshortTextBox()
        : base(@"^[0-9]$")
    {
    }

    protected override bool TryParse(out ushort val)
    {
        return UInt16.TryParse(Text, out val);
    }
}
```

I'm new to this whole custom-control-making, so if you see some rookie mistakes or ways to improve my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can avoid inheritance here ("Favor Composition Over Inheritance") and use Attached Behavior instead.

Also, did you take a look at MaskedTextBox from Extended WPF Toolkit (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox)?

Comment: Yes, i did look at the masked textbox, but it is not quite what i needed. It filters input, based on string format specified. And i wanted to filter input, based on parsing logic of specified type. But i kind of like your idea about attached behaviors. I've never made my own, but i'll certainly give it a try. Hopefully i will be able to keep my implementation generic. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your code is missing the most is documentation and some better naming. The constructor takes a regex string (with a very generic name `regexPattern`) and you *also* have to override `TryParse()`. There is absolutely no indication of why both are needed, without looking at the source of `CustomTextBox`.

Also, the name `CustomTextBox` pretty much doesn't say anything, I think you should think of a better name for it, one that actually describes how is the type different from normal `TextBox`.